# bash shell: grepping two strings in same line and use it in if-condition

Tags: linux, bash, shell

```
grep string1 file1.txt | grep -q string2
if [ $? == 0 ]; then
    echo "both string1 and 2 found"
else
    echo "either or both missing"
fi
```

I need to find both string1 and string 2 in same line from file1.txt, is there any better way to write this or this is the good already? thanks for all the help, I am new to shell programming.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Its pretty good already if the order doesn't matter, but you can shorten it to:

`grep string1 file1.txt | grep -q string2 && echo found || echo not found`

Answer (score 2):

you can use

```
grep -e "string1.*string2" file1.txt
```

so long as you're expecting string2 to come second and there is no overlap

Alternatively the grep piped into grep is the standard approach. Maybe using a variable

```
result=`grep string1 file1.txt | grep string2`
if [ `echo "$result"|wc -w` == 0 ];then
  echo "a"
else
  echo "b"
fi
```

Comment: for when order doesn't matter you can OR it with the alternate order `grep -e "string1.*string2|string2.*string1" file1.txt`

Answer (score 0):

Usually, you only need to use `$?` if you need to compare it against several different values. In this case, you only care about 0-vs-non-zero, so just run the `grep` commands in the `if` statement itself.

```
if grep string1 file1.txt | grep -q string2; then
    echo "both string1 and 2 found"
else
    echo "either or both missing"
fi
```